# Updating model relation in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

In my Laravel application I have a link between a `User` and a `Team` where the `department` field in the table `users` is related to the `name` field in the `teams` table.

This is represented by the given relation:

```
/**
 * Specify that a user belongs to only one team
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function team()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Team::class, 'department', 'name');
}
```

Obviously, an issue with this approach is if you change the team name the users are then orphaned.

To rectify this I tried the following:

```
/**
 * Update this team in the database
 * If the team name changes also update the associated users
 *
 * @param Team $team
 * @return void
 */
public function update(UpdateTeam $request, Team $team)
{
    $data = $request->validated();

    if ($data['name'] != $team->name) {
        foreach ($team->users as $user) {

            $user->fill([
                'department' => $data['name'],
            ])->save();
        }
    }

    $team->fill($data)->save();
}
```

But in the `User` model I also have this accessor:

```
/**
 * Get a direct link to this user's profile using the global route helper
 */
public function getProfilePageAttribute()
{
    return $this->department ? route('profile.show', [$this->team->slug, $this->username]) : null;
}
```

As I update the team name this throws an error because during the change `$this->team` is effectively `null`.

I have a `TeamObserver` and tried to hook this behavior to the `updating` event but the relation of `$team->users` would also return `null` as it would use the current attribute and not the old attribute.

Is there any way around this without mapping the team names to ids in the user table? Mainly due to the fact that the data provided used the names as a department.

Is it possible to tell a relation to use the old attributes whilst updating?

Comment: The better approach with changing department-names - and making sure that the values in the users-table are updated, is making that column a foregin-key of the department name with an `ON UPDATE CASCADE`.

Comment: You mean at the actual database level?

Comment: Correct. That way, if the name of the department changes, it automatically follows in the user-table.

Comment: You know I've used cascade before and had no idea it did that...

Comment: `CASCADE` means "*follow this action*". So you can have `ON UPDATE SET NULL`, which sets it to null, `ON UPDATE CASCADE` which makes the child-table update to the parent's value, `ON DELETE SET NULL` and `ON DELETE CASCADE`. Quite handy! That's what foregin keys are really good for - ensuring data integrity.

Comment: You should write this as an answer so I can upvote and accept it. This was a case of gross overengineering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your schema, add a foreign-key constraint between the two tables, with an `ON UPDATE CASCADE` (and maybe `ON DELETE SET NULL`?), that way - you ensure that the name of the users department will always be the same value as the parent (department name).

For the schema (migration) for the user's table, add the foreign key

```
$table->foreign('department')
      ->references('name')
      ->on('teams')
      ->onUpdate('cascade')
      // ->onDelete('set null');
```

Keep in mind that both columns that are referenced (`users.department` and `teams.name`) will have to be exactly the same type and length. There must also be no mismatch of data (meaning that an user cannot be a member of a department that does not exist in `teams`).

If you want to add it to a new migration, you can do that!

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function($table) {
        $table->foreign('department')
              ->references('name')
              ->on('teams')
              ->onUpdate('cascade')
              // ->onDelete('set null');
    });
}
```

Comment: Could I add this in a new migration using Schema::table?

Comment: Yes, but ensure that (as mentioned in the answer) the columns are of exact same data-type and length, and that there is no mis-match of data. You'll get an error if there is a mismatch when you run the migration.

Comment: I received this error: DOException::("SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails"). I'm pressuming this is because migrate:refresh is dropping the parent table

Comment: Sounds like some user has a `department` that does not exist in `teams`.

Comment: After going through the data I was given there were indeed major inconsistencies, so this was actually a good exercise in data cleansing.  This is because the seeds would fail to run if they broke the integrity constraints.